# update all the nodes with same data on a single update

Tags: apache-2.2, php, load-balancing

Basically i owns 3 systems where one act as a Balancer Node , and the data for the websites resides over the other two.

The Problem is :

i want to update all the 2 nodes with the same data (means .php files , which my website is designed) when i update either one of them . note: .php source files have to be updated

what can i do?

Doubt :
i have also one doubt to ask can i basically call the group (balancer system and the nodes ) as a cloud ?

Comment: Do you want to simultaneously update your both node?

Comment: yes thats it , bu i may update only a common source

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a git repo...
basically what we do is we create a GIT repo and push our code to it, and on the webserver, we clone that repository on deployment path e.g. /var/www/html/xyz
and evry time a developer commits to the repo, there is a custom script that is triggered to pull new files from git to target webservers...

Comment: You can also try lsyncd

Comment: or u can try incrond + rsync